# How create correct ufw rule from iptables mangle?

Tags: iptables, ufw

I created mangle.init and mangle.rules.
mangle.rules:

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# mangle Table rules
-A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --sport 0:1024 -j TOS --set-tos Minimize-Delay
-A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --sport 1025:65535 -j TOS --set-tos Maximize-Throughput
-A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --dport 0:1024 -j TOS --set-tos Minimize-Delay
-A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --dport 1025:65535 -j TOS --set-tos Maximize-Throughput

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

But rules don`t work. How create correct ufw rule from iptables mangle?
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, ufw 0.35-0ubuntu2, kernel 4.4.0-34-generic, iptables v1.6.0